# Default values to static variables

Tags: php, static, traits

Is it possible to use `Traits` for giving default values to static variables? Consider the following example.

```
  trait Properties {
     public static $properties = [];
  }

  class Base {
     use Properties;
  }
  Base::$properties[0] = 'val1';
  Base::$properties[1] = 'val2';
  Base::$properties[2] = 'val3';

  class Derived extends Base {
     use Properties;
  }
  Derived::$properties[1] = 'changed value';
  Derived::$properties[3] = 'new value';

  var_dump(Base::$properties);
  var_dump(Derived::$properties);
```

I would like the output to be something like

```
  array (size=3)
    0 => string 'val1' (length=4)
    1 => string 'val2' (length=4)
    2 => string 'val3' (length=4)
  array (size=4)
    0 => string 'val1' (length=4)
    1 => string 'changed value' (length=13)
    2 => string 'val3' (length=4)
    3 => string 'new value' (length=9)
```

The example does not work, since `Base and Properties define the same property ($properties) in the composition of Derived`. If I remove the `use Properties` from `Derived`, the `$properties` variable is the same for both `Base` and `Derived`, and any changes applies to both classes. I hoped to get around this by including `Properties` in both classes. Are there any nice ways to achieve what I want? I don't have to use `Traits`, I just thought this could help.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. It does not work indeed and that's actually how it should be: you either overload the variable (`use properties` in `Derived`) or extend it (`use properties` only in `Base`). You're trying to extend the existing properties but also adding new ones: you should therefore use a single getter/setter per property, allowing you to have the original ones plus the ones specific to the child class, as commonly seen in inheritence models. The fact that it is static is not really part of the problem, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a pretty straightforward object-oriented style. 
It goes without traits, but with method-accessors in place of attribute-accessors:

```
class Base {
  private static $properties;

  public static function getProperties() {
    if (!isset(self::$properties)) {
      self::$properties = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']; // use `array('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` with PHP<5.4
    }
    return self::$properties;
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  private static $properties; // has nothing to do with parent::$properties! 

  public static function getProperties() {
    if (!isset(self::$properties)) {
      self::$properties = parent::getProperties();
      self::$properties[1] = 'changed value';
      self::$properties[] = 'new value';
    }
    return self::$properties;
  }
}

var_dump(Base::getProperties());
var_dump(Derived::getProperties());
```

Note that there's no risk of modifying internal arrays from outside with method-accessors, and that there's *practically* no performance impact of using methods with memoization.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to your suggestion, but also using a `Trait` containing every logic concerning `$properties`. This way I don't have to copy the `getProperties()` function into every class. Thanks!